# Upgrading spring-integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We are trying to upgrade our application to use the latest spring framework libraries.
I have a class which is not available ( or appears that way) in the latest spring integration jars (i.e. 2.2.x). It was available in 1.0.4 which is the one we are currently using.
    import org.springframework.integration.channel.MessageChannelTemplate;

Has this jar just been moved or removed? I can't seem to find any details on this. Should we be using something else now instead?

Here is the [link to the migration guides](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) I was looking at.

Any information or guidance would be great - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now `org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate`

Comment: Correct - 

https://fisheye.springsource.org/changelog/spring-integration?cs=cc8d44528080c97bd7e369e42e72d302482c8655

I will add a note to the migration guide.